# Virtual member function changes result of typeid - why?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeid

this code is working fine and prints "yes":

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
     virtual void talk() {  cout << "person talking" << endl;}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void work() { cout << "employee working" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A* pA = new B();

    if (typeid(*pA) == typeid(B))
        cout << "yes" << endl; // this is printed
    else
        cout << "no" << endl;
}
```

but if i remove the virtual keyword it will print "no"

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
     void talk() {  cout << "person talking" << endl;}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void work() { cout << "employee working" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A* pA = new B();

    if (typeid(*pA) == typeid(B))
        cout << "yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no" << endl; // this is printed
}
```

why is that happening?
why does the virtualness of a method impact the type of the object?

**EDIT:**
To make things more confusing, this works fine:

```
((B*)(pA))->work(); // works fine, prints "employee working"
```

So why is the *pA regarded only as class A object (when there is no virtual keyword) but can  still call child's work() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `typeid` works. A class that has no virtual members is a *non-polymorphic type* and carries no run-time type information. Hence there's no way to determine it's type at run time.

See [[expr.typeid]/p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.typeid#2):

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the type of the most derived object (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers.

And [[expr.typeid]/p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.typeid#3):

> When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the static type of the expression.

*Static type* means the type is determined simply at compile-time (for `A*` it is thus `A`).